# Android - Determine what loaded the Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, homescreen

so I'm working on an android, project, and I've made a login security screen for the app, that the user can turn on or off because the app does contain sensitive data.

I've got code on the main activity that if the time stamp requires a login, it'll push the user to the login activity and allow them to login. The issue is that, if the user is in the app for a while, and returns to the main activity, the onResume() is called, and the PIN login could be called again due to the fact the time stamp expired.

Is there a way to check if the app came from another activity within the App, or if it came from the home screen when it was launched?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! If you find a response is helpful, please up vote it. If the response successfully answers your question, please click the green check mark next to it to accept the answer. Also please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask for advice on how to write a good question

Answer (score 0):

So the real solution to this problem isn't to try to figure out how to tell where you Activity was started from, but to use an [AbstractAccountAuthenticator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AbstractAccountAuthenticator.html). It has a whole bunch of stuff built in so that only the people who are supposed to see credentials are allowed to see those credentials.

Comment: from what I've seen with the AbstractAccountAuthenticator, its a whole login system, which I've already developed one specific to the project. I just need a way to determine what loaded the App. Need to know if it was loaded from the home screen, or another Activity within the Appliaction